# Catching keypresses C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, keypress

I am using a simple loop for catching user keypresses;

```
while (1)
{
    for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
    {
       if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767){
         //Do stuff
       }
    }
}
```

Which will 'do stuff' when a user presses a certain key, however obviously as it's looping indefinitely and as i'm new to C++ it's taking up 100% CPU which is not good for a simple input.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried the Sleep() function (if I put it in the 'for loop' it misses keypresses and if I put it in the 'while loop' it doesn't lower CPU at all, afaik)

How can I make it catch keypresses the same, but use not nearly as much CPU; am I missing a trick? I'm sure most programs catch keypresses and you don't see all them using 100%!

Thanks alot.

Comment: you can't do this using a linear algorithm... you need to add a listener to your program. google that.

Comment: Use a hook. `GetMessage` will idle until a key event occurs. For a dirtier solution, add in a `Sleep(10);` or something to the loop.

Comment: In the past I have used a combination of `RegisterHotkey` and `UnregisterHotkey`. I only wanted to detect keypresses when the window was in focus however, so I called `UnregisterHotkey` when the window went out of focus and registered it back when the window went back in focus. Maybe these functions will help you. If you don't unregister the hotkeys while the window is out of focus it might mess up other application hotkeys.

Answer (score 3):

Put your infinite loop in a worker thread, and have it sleep for some reasonable interval on each iteration.  C++11 makes this pretty easy:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::chrono::milliseconds THREAD_WAIT = 50;

int keypress = -1;

void GetKeyPress()
{
   while (1)
   {
       for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
       {
          int k = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
          if (/*whatever condition needs to be satisfied*/)
              keypress = k;
       }
       if (keypress != -1) break; //Use this only if you have td.join() below
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(THREAD_WAIT);
   }
}

int main(void)
{
   ...

   std::thread td( GetKeyPress );
   td.join(); //If you want to block until the user presses a key, otherwise remove.

   //If no join(), do the rest of your program, checking in on keypress when need be

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check following link that explains Proper use of GetAsyncKeyState() with example code.
http://www.mpgh.net/forum/31-c-c-programming/120656-proper-use-getasynckeystate.html

Hope this link might help you to solve your problem

**Edited:**
The GetAsyncKeyState() function is not ideal for what you are trying to do.

All it does is simply check the actual, current-at-this-nanosecond position of a key on the keyboard. Doing that is almost always incorrect.

Instead, read the console input using the proper input functions. Please find below the sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD        mode;          /* Preserved console mode */
    INPUT_RECORD event;         /* Input event */
    BOOL         done = FALSE;  /* Program termination flag */
    unsigned int counter = 0;   /* The number of times 'Esc' is pressed */

    /* Don't use binary for text files, OK?  ;-) */
    FILE* myfile = fopen( "example.txt", "w" );

    /* Get the console input handle */
    HANDLE hstdin = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );

    /* Preserve the original console mode */
    GetConsoleMode( hstdin, &mode );

    /* Set to no line-buffering, no echo, no special-key-processing */
    SetConsoleMode( hstdin, 0 );

    /* Give the user instructions */
    printf(
        "Press Escape as many times as you like.\n"
        "Press anything else to quit.\n\n"
        );

    while (!done)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject( hstdin, 0 ) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)  /* if kbhit */
        {
            DWORD count;  /* ignored */

            /* Get the input event */
            ReadConsoleInput( hstdin, &event, 1, &count );

            /* Only respond to key release events */
            if ((event.EventType == KEY_EVENT)
            &&  !event.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
                switch (event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
                {
                    case VK_ESCAPE:
                        counter++;
                        fprintf( myfile, "Escape: %d\n", counter );
                        printf( "Button pressed!\n" );
                        break;
                    default:
                        done = TRUE;
                }
        }
    }

    /* All done! */
    printf( "You pressed the Escape key %d times\n", counter );
    fclose( myfile );
    SetConsoleMode( hstdin, mode );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
while (!kbhit());
```

This might help.

Comment: My compiler does not recognize kbhit (DevC++) which complier will that command work in?

Comment: Works now thanks, although still very high CPU, i'll try a hook or listener like the other comments suggest. Thanks.